# Does $this->get() only work for app routes in Laravel tests?

Tags: laravel

I am trying to check if the file *robots.txt* exists, but my test returns `404`. Visiting the url `website.test/robots.txt` manually works. This leads me to believe that the `$this->get()` method only works for defined routes.

Here is my trivial test that fails:

```
$response = $this->get(env('APP_URL') . '/robots.txt');
$response->assertSuccessful();
```

Does `$this->get()` only work for defined routes in Laravel tests, or am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, `->get()` will only work with defined routes as it doesn't actually make an HTTP request, it just creates a `Request` internally and then returns the response.

The easiest way to check that the file exists would be to do just that:

```
$this->assertTrue(file_exists(public_path('robots.txt')));
```

[file_exists() docs](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.file-exists.php)
[public_path() docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/helpers#method-public-path)